# Making multiple pages in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm making a very simple app, the main page has 5 buttons, each should open a new page with different text views and buttons, since I'm new to android I want to know what is the best practice for this situation?

Should I make every page as an activity ? Or will that take a lot of resources from the phone?

Comment: there is no "pages" in Android :( only "screens", "activities" and "fragments". You should some "Hello, World !" tutorials to understand the Android basis and how it manages the differents screens of an app ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have a view fill up the entire screen you should make each page an Activity.

Android manages itself the activity stack so you dont have to worry about.

Just make sure you declare it on the manifiest, or use the Android studio assistant to make a new activity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks , 
I've started with making new activities with the help of Abdroid studio